# Tool to analyse programming languages used in a project

Tags: statistics, programming-languages

The only tool I can find so far is https://github.com/github/linguist

I am sure this tool works fine in some situations.  I get a lot of false positives and it misses some languages.  A project consisting of some C, C++, ObjC and it claims to see C, C++, D, Fortran, Shell, Python.  If I analyze the ObjC directory all by itself then it works fine but misses all the other languages.  Very flakey.

So does anyone have a good tool to generate some basic stats on which languages are being used in a very large project?

UPDATE:

Tried https://github.com/blackducksw/ohcount/

Similar story to linguist but provided a ton more details.  A bit hit and miss at times though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [SLOCCount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) a try. It can identify numerous programming languages and does some interesting statistics (such as estimated development costs).

Comment: Just tried SLOCCount and it gave the most accurate reading so far.  It is in the ubuntu repos so took no time at all to get ready.

Comment: Thanks for the pro tip on that program.  Google searching for such a tool for some reason proved very difficult.